# Defining functions in header file with primitives in other header file

Tags: c++, function, header, primitive

I'm trying to declare functions I later use in my main code in a header file. I made one header file in which I declared the function primitives, one file where I defined the functions, and a main file containing the actual code. The structure can be seen as follows (I'll illustrate the problem as general as possible without my specific code):

Header file (let's call this header.h):

```
#ifndef header_H
#define header_H
(some return type) function(arguments);
... other function declarations...
#endif
```

Function defining file (let's call this function.h):

```
#ifndef function_H
#define function_H
#include header.h
(some return type) function(arguments){
             function body
}
... other function definitions...
#endif
```

Main code (let's call this main.cc):

```
#include header.h
#include function.h

int main{
        ....
        use the functions defined in the headers
        ....
        return 0;
}
```

When I include the functions I wrote in this way I get an error message saying I defined the functions multiple times and it won't compile. What am I doing wrong? Is it not allowed to declare function primitives in another header than the header in which you define the functions? Or is there something wrong with how I include the headers?

An example of a specific error i get is the following (for a function called drawhist):

```
tmp/ccoADQB4.o: In function `plothist(TH1D*, TString, TFile*)':
main.cc:(.text+0x5a0): multiple definition of `drawhist(TH1D*, TString, TFile*)'
/tmp/cclAZJEr.o:function.cc:(.text+0x5a0): first defined here
```

EDIT: It turned out I defined the file in which i declared my functions as a .cc file instead of a .h file.

Comment: you can show the errors?

Comment: Ok sure give me a minute

Comment: I guess, you have one more *.cc file, that includes function.h, that leads to multiple defined symbols.

Comment: I only have one .cc file

Comment: Sorry to waste everyone's time, i declared one of the headers as a .cc file and noticed it only now

Comment: Should I delete the question now that it turned out I made a dumb mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your **function.h**  to **function.cc**, and in your **function.cc** file, put **#include "header.h"**.
In your **main.cc**, put **#include "header.h"**, then it should work

Comment: Well it turned out I declared the file where i defined the functions as function.cc instead of function.h Changing this solved the Issue